# Rails: rescue class inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a job that has a `run` method that looks like this:

```
def perform(share, document)
  @history = document.scheduled_posts.find_by(provider: share[:provider])
  job = ProviderJob.new(document, share)
  begin
    job.run
    @history.update_columns(response: 'posted', status: 'complete')
  rescue StandardError => e
    @history.update_columns(response: e.message, status: 'error')
    raise Errors::FailedJob, e.message
  rescue FbGraph2::Exception::Unauthorized, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, Mailchimp::UserUnknownError, LinkedIn::OAuthError, Errors::MissingAuth => e
    @history.update_columns(response: e.message, status: 'unauthorised')
    raise Errors::FailedJob, e.message
  end
end
```

Even if `Errors::MissingAuth` is raised, the `StandardError` block catches it because it inherits from it. How can I ensure that the correct block catches the specified exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those rescue blocks are executed in order. You should put more specific ones first. Move that `StandardError` one as last.

Comment: You're right, thank-you. I had read conflicting reports on the ordering of the rescue blocks and I wasn't getting the result I was after. Cheers.

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Answer (score 2):

The rescue blocks are run in sequence.  Because Errors::MissingAuth inherits from StandardError, the StandardError block will always fire first.  You should change the precedence of the rescue blocks, for instance:

```
def perform(share, document)
  @history = document.scheduled_posts.find_by(provider: share[:provider])
  job = ProviderJob.new(document, share)
  begin
    job.run
    @history.update_columns(response: 'posted', status: 'complete')
  rescue FbGraph2::Exception::Unauthorized, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, Mailchimp::UserUnknownError, LinkedIn::OAuthError, Errors::MissingAuth => e
    @history.update_columns(response: e.message, status: 'unauthorised')
    raise Errors::FailedJob, e.message
  rescue StandardError => e
    @history.update_columns(response: e.message, status: 'error')
    raise Errors::FailedJob, e.message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If the other answers work, I think that's a better approach. I wasn't aware of that, and started typing another answer, so I'll just include it anyway.

I am assuming all the errors here inherit from StandardError. In which case you can use a single rescue, and configure behavior based on the class of the error raised:

```
rescue StandardError => e
  status = [
    FbGraph2::Exception::Unauthorized, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized,
    Mailchimp::UserUnknownError, LinkedIn::OAuthError, Errors::MissingAuth
  ].include?(e.class) ? 'unauthorized' : 'error'
  @history.update_columns(response: e.message, status: status)
  raise Errors::FailedJob, e.message
end
```